# XPath positional filtering not working as expected

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following HTML

```
<html>
[snip]
<table>
 [snip]
 <tr><td>One</td><td>1-1</td></tr>
 [snip]
</table>
[snip]
<table>
 [snip]
 <tr><td>One</td><td>1-1-1</td></tr>
 [snip]
</table>
</html>
```

..and I'm trying to get the value "1-1-1" using the following xpath

```
//tr[td[1] = 'One'][2]/td[2]
```

I'd describe this as retrieve the 2nd td elements value from the 2nd tr element that contains at least one td element where the 1st td elements value is 'One'.  I've tried various alterations like `position()=last()` but to no avail.

I only know that the 2nd occurrence of the text "One" in the first cell of a parent row identifies the row from which I can pluck the text from the 2nd cell ... so something hardcoded won't work (e.g. `//table[2]/tr[1]/td[2]`).

Can someone tell me why the xpath above won't work?  I've looked at the w3c site and found xpaths like:

```
child::*[self::chapter or self::appendix][position()=last()]
```

Described as:

> selects the last chapter or appendix child of the context node

..which is similar to what I'm trying to do but perhaps the nesting is disallowed..

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**

Use:

```
(//tr[td[1]='One'])[2]/td[2]
```

**Explanation**

> I'd describe this as retrieve the 2nd td elements value from the 2nd
>   tr element that contains at least one td element where the 1st td
>   elements value is 'One'.

What `//tr[td[1]='One'][2]` actually selects is all `tr` elements having a first `td` child whose value is `One` and *that are the the second such `tr` of their parent*.

Why? This expression:

```
//tr[td[1]='One'][2]
```

...is equivalent to:

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/child::tr[td[1]='One'][2]
```

Written that way, it's easier to see that the `[2]` applies earlier than you originally thought. Adding parenthesis:

```
(/descendant-or-self::node()/child::tr[td[1]='One'])[2]
```

...causes us to first select all `tr` elements having a first `td` child whose value is `One` *and then* takes the second node from that set.

Comment: Ouch, I should have realized that distinction.  Thanks a ton for the explanation!

Comment: @user1098705: This is one of the most FAQ in XPath -- there are many answers similar to this -- just read them and try to remember that there are anomalies when using the `//` pseudo-operator -- more than just it dismall speed of selection.

Comment: @lwburk FYI: I edited your answer. `//tr[td[1]='One'][2]` is not equivalent to `descendant-or-self::tr[td[1]='One'][2]`. Because the text you wrote in italics is true for the first-mentioned XPath, but not for the latter one, so I assumed this was unintentional and OK to be edited.

Comment: I understand the dismal performance implied by use of '//' but the HTML being parsed is 3rd party and rather than hard-code the location of a specific table (fragile to insertion/deletion of any previous sibling tables), I chose to locate a table based on known column contents.  I'll search more in-depth to find closely related questions as well.  Again, thanks for all of the help!